# Find a cell with a specific value and delete all rows after

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a little over my head at work.

I'm working on a quick Excel tool to help me do reports at my job. The order management software we have can export to Excel but the data needs some trimming. There are 3 columns that have information that I need (C, D and R).

What I need to do is find a specific value in column C, delete everything after that, and delete all rows except for D and R. So far I have been able through recording macros accomplish the last half of this but I am having trouble with the first.

This is what I have so far, generated through the macro recording.

```
Sub SortCopy()
'
' SortCopy Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    Range("A:C,E:Q,S:AN").Select
    Range("S1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:B").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorting").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorting").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A3436") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorting").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B4000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("A1:B1102").Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

I have no experience in VBA. I am way out of my league with this one.

Comment: Just a few points of clarity: What's the 'specific value'? Also do you mean delete all /columns/ except D and R?

Comment: Also is the sorting a necessary step or is that a way of finding the specific value you're after? I've got a method in mind, but if you need it sorted in a certain way it won't be suitable necessarily.

Comment: Its a bit convoluted. The number is a client's order number. When I filter out other department's orders, while they do not show up in our software, they still appear when I export the data to excel. I found that all orders that do not apply to the filter will be in rows after the last order that appears in our software. I would need to delete all these rows and then delete all columns that do not contain information I need to generate this report.

Comment: The sorting at the end is just to remove blank rows that are a quirk of how the excel file is formatted when I export to it.

Answer (score 0):

VBA isn't that scary, just takes a but of trial and error. Recording macros like you have done here is the best way to learn and see how it works. Unfortunately macro recording won't show you how to do conditional (if-else) statements or looping, which I think is what you need to do what you want. Here is some basic looping code that you can add to your macro:

```
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
' start loop
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty

    ' check cell for specific value
    If ActiveCell.Value = "whatever" Then
        found = True
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If

    If found Then
        ' delete row
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete (xlShiftUp)
    Else
        ' move down a cell
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If

Loop
```

There are more efficient ways to do this that don't involve selecting cells, but I think this is the easiest to understand and see it working in the debugger (press the F8 key).

Comment: The specific value would change each time I run the report. See my replies to @neophlegm for a bit more context. Would there be a way to say, enter the order number I need to find in cell A1 and have the function search for that value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it will do what you want.

```
Sub Trim_Data()
    Dim X as Integer
    Dim Last_Val as String
    Last_Val = InputBox(“Enter the value you wish to find in the data:”,”Enter last Value”,””)
    If Last_Val = “” then Exit Sub
    For X = 1 to 10000
        If Range(“C” & X).Value = Last_Val then Goto Found_It
    Next X
    Last_Val = MsgBox(“The entered Value was not found.”, vbcritical)
    Exit Sub
Found_It:
    Range(“A” & (X + 1) & “:A10000”).EntireRow.Delete
    Range(“S1:ZZ1”).EntireColumn.Delete
    Range(“E1:Q1”).EntireColumn.Delete
    Range(“A1:C1”).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I try to run this code on the following lines.

`Last_Val = InputBox(“Enter the value you wish to find in the data:”,”Enter last Value”,””)`

and

`Range(“A” & (X + 1) & “:A10000”).EntireRow.Delete
    Range(“S1:ZZ1”).EntireColumn.Delete
    Range(“E1:Q1”).EntireColumn.Delete
    Range(“A1:C1”).EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: I was just informed by another member that they had to replace my Quotation marks individually in the code I’ve written for it to work (must be some keyboard setting issue). Try this first, and if it doesn’t help, let me know and I will investigate.

Comment: Actually, I had did a bit of experimenting and I came up with a code that does about 1/3 of what I need it to.

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim StringToFind As String

    StringToFind = Application.InputBox("Enter string to find", "Find string")

    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("c:c").Select
    Selection.Find(what:=StringToFind).Offset(1, -2).Activate
    
End Sub`

This will have the user input an order number and then select cell A of the row immediately after it.

Comment: What I need to do now is find a way to remove all rows after that one and I should be fine. I was messing around and I was able to get the `Range` function(? I'm not sure the correct terminology) but I can't seem to marry that with the code I already have.

Comment: @RyanWinter just take all my code after Found_It and insert a line between your code and mine that says X = Selection.Row - 1 and that should work!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that might work. Instead deleting the data each time, leave the data in its own sheet, then create a view based on that data. I'm using ADO, which may be unfamiliar more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic)

Here is my data setup, all the data is in a sheet called `Raw`. I created a new sheet called `View` which is where the data will go after the query is complete. I mocked your dataset up by creating 18 different fields (or columns). I named them `Field 1`, `Field 2`, `Field 3`...all the way to `Field 18, again this is in the data sheet. Make sure your data has headers, e.g. meaningful names on the same row.

I'm assuming you are looking for a `String` and not a `Date`, or `Numeric` type so the query is designed as a simple example so only works with a `String`. It can be modified for different types :)

To be clear, I'm referring to this part of the code:

`SQL = "Select [Field 3], [Field 4], [Field 18] from [Raw$] Where [Field 3] = '" & LookFor & "'"`

Running the sub `caller`, should show a result in the View sheet.

```
Public Sub CreateView(LookFor As String)
    Dim Conn        As Object
    Dim SQL         As String
    Dim rs          As Object
    Dim outSheet    As Worksheet
    Const adStateOpen = 1

    'The view sheet is where the data will go to
    Set outSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("View")

    'Field 3 = Column C, Field 4 = Column D
    'If your field has headers use that, otherwise, add headers
    SQL = "Select [Field 3], [Field 4], [Field 18] from [Raw$] Where [Field 3] = '" & LookFor & "'"

    Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    'Connect to current spreadsheet
    Conn.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
                            ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';"
    Conn.Open

    'Get the recordset
    Set rs = Conn.Execute(SQL)

    'Add the data to the view sheet
    With outSheet
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("Field 1", "Field 3", "Field18")
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        .Activate
    End With

    'Close the connection if it's open
    If Conn.State = adStateOpen Then Conn.Close
End Sub

Private Sub caller()
    'This is the caller routine
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim searchCriteria As String
    searchCriteria = InputBox("Enter the search field", "Enter criteria")
    CreateView (searchCriteria)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```